# Spring Security "No bean named 'filterChainProxy' available" error

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I followed several tutorials to use Spring security but I still have the same "*No bean named 'filterChainProxy' available*" issue.

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart Exception starting filter [filterChainProxy]
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'filterChainProxy' available
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:686)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1210)
```

I use the follow configuration:

***web.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
     version="3.0">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
    <filter-name>filterChainProxy</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>filterChainProxy</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

***applicationContext-security.xml***

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
         xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="ROLE_USER" />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="blabla" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

***spring-mvc-servlet.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


<context:component-scan base-package="com.medkhelifi.tutorials.spring.springregistration"/>
<context:annotation-config/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

I Don't know what I'm missing.
Thank you.
I use:
Spring: 5.0.5.RELEASE
Spring-Security: 3.2.5

Comment: Do you have a handler which implements interface Filter? Can you show the code ?

Comment: The handler should have 'filterChainProxy' as its bean id

Comment: The error is because you have a `DelegatingFilterProxy` named `filterChainProxy` this will look for a bean named `filterChainProxy`. However Spring Security registers the filter chain with the name `springSecurityFilterChain`. So just change the name of the filter in the `web.xml`.

Comment: Thank you @M.Deinum I solved my error, can you please post your comment as a response so wen can close the topic. Thank you.

Comment: I doubt however you are using Spring 5.2.16 as the latest version is 5.0.5.

Comment: Yes @M.Deinum you're right, I confused with Hibernate version :)

Comment: Yes @M.Deinum you're right, I confused with Hibernate version :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Security register a bean named `springSecurityFilterChain` as mentioned in the [Spring Security Reference Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-web-xml).

The [`DelegatingFilterProxy`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/DelegatingFilterProxy.html), by default, will try to detect a bean with the same name as the name of the filter. In your case `filterChainProxy`. However this fails because, as stated, there is a bean created named `springSecurityFilterChain`.

Now you can do 2 things to fix it

1. Rename your filter to `springSecurityFilterChain` as stated [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-web-xml)
2. Include in `<alias name="filterChainProxy" alias="springSecurityFilterChain"/>` if you cannot modify the `web.xml`.